# Create a file whose size in bytes is the percentage of free space on a disk

Tags: disk-space, bsd, ksh

I needed a command-line method of creating a file whose size in bytes is the percentage of free space on a disk. I intend to run it via cron every five minutes, but first a shell script will do.

The target platform is the BSD4.3 environment in DOMAIN/OS, so I have `ksh`, `awk`, `sed` and the usual BSD commands, but not GNU versions.

I can run a command `lvolfs -a` (*not* a BSD command) which lists volume free space in this format:

```
  # free   # total   % free         node id  entry directory
  732532   1295672       57           4D72C   /
 3787184   4165732       91           52055   //tr3
-------------------------------
 4519716   5461404    82.76%      2 volumes.
```

so it seems straightforward to extract the values, in this case 57 and 91, identifying them by the hexadecimal node ids, 4D72C and 52055, respectively.

I immediately thought 'dd can do it', so concentrating on node 4D72C first, I came up with:

```
/com/lvolfs -a | \
    awk -e '/4D72C/ { print $3 }' | \
    sed -e 's|^|dd if=/dev/rdsk of=//tr2/test/data/tr2.free bs=|' | \
    sed -e 's|$| count=1|' >//tr2/archive/dirlist

. //tr2/archive/dirlist
```

And `dirlist` looks like

```
dd if=/dev/rdsk of=//tr2/test/data/tr2.free bs=57 count=1
```

It works, and I'll need to repeat something like this for node 52055, but I wonder if `dd` is the only way using really basic BSD commands. Would anyone have any suggestions?

---

EDIT: Some more background information about the target system ... it's an HP/Apollo DN433 'Engineering Workstation', the bee's knees when it was released in the early '80s, but now about as impressive as a 486DX system. The native OS attempts to imitate Unix by providing a BSD4.3 'environment' with a reasonable set of BSD commands, but there is a temptation to mix BSD and *Aegis* commands (like `lvolfs`) as I've done here.

I have two workstations, and each controls Automatic Test Equipment. The two workstations are networked together and the network root directory `//` includes tr2 (node id 4D72C) and tr3 (node id 52055). *You don't really want or need to know all this stuff* - I'd just like to give the impression that nothing should be taken for granted. I don't want anyone to waste too much time on this stuff - that's *my* job, but I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have. The Korn Shell is still a bit of a mystery to me.

UPDATE: The `df -a` command in DOMAIN/OS gives

```
$ df -a
Filesystem         kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/wn96a        1295672  563904  731768    44%    //tr2
/dev/wn96a        4165732  379804 3785928     9%    //tr3
                ----------------------------------
                  5461300  943700 4517600    17%
```

Which, since it mentions the more familiar names **tr2** and **tr3**, might be preferable. The only *slight* hurdle is that we get disk space *used* not *free*, but this can be overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dd`. You say "lvolfs -a (not a BSD command)". Do you have `df`? That would be a more standard and portable way to get the volume usage information.

It shouldn't be necessary to create a temporary script file to do this. You should be able to do:

```
dd if=/dev/rdsk of=//tr2/test/data/tr2.free bs=\
$(/com/lvolfs -a | awk -e '/4D72C/ { print $3 }') count=1
```

or

```
avail=$(df /usr | awk -e 'NR==2 { print $5 }')
avail=${avail%*%}    # strip off the percent sign
dd if=/dev/rdsk of=//tr2/test/data/tr2.free bs=$avail count=1
```

(depending on how your filesystems are organized and what the output of `df` looks like).

You could even put the second one in a loop:

```
for fs in / /usr /home    # list the ones you want to include
do
    avail=$(df $fs | awk -e 'NR==2 { print $5 }')
    avail=${avail%*%}     # strip off the percent sign
    # create a file on the particular filesystem/mount point
    dd if=/dev/rdsk of=//$fs/test/data/tr2.free bs=$avail count=1
done
```

Examine this carefully before you use it to make sure it does what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The `lvolfs` command is native DOMAIN/OS and it gives a different format to `df`, of course. I prefer the format given by `lvolfs`. I don't really have to worry about portability. I'll try using `df` but it will have to wait until Monday when I go back to work.

Comment: Been thinking about the `df` command, and how closely its output resembles what we're used to. I've edited the question to add a little more background information about the peculiar system this is to work on.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I decided to stick with `lvolfs -a` but I used your idea of eliminating the temporary file. I must try pushing `ksh` a little more on this ancient equipment.